# Python recursion confusion

Tags: python, recursion

```
def recursion(x):
    answer = 0
    if( x > 10 ):
        answer +=1
        return recursion( x - 1)
    return answer
recursion(15)
```

I'm just playing around with python and recursive functions and made this, but strangely having errors.

Why is this printing 0 instead of my expected answer of:

5

Comment: because answer can only be 1 or 0 ...

Comment: What do you mean? I'm returning answer, which started off as 0, but as x > 10, im adding 1 to answer every loop. So first x is 15,then 14,13,12,11 which is 5 loops adding 1 to answer. So shouldn't it return 5?

Comment: `answer` is a local variable. It is declared and set to zero each time `recursion()` is called.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add the recursive call to your answer, not return it

```
def recursion(x):
    answer = 0
    if( x > 10 ):
        answer = answer + 1 + recursion( x - 1)
    return answer
```

sometimes it is helpful to step through your code ... debuggers do this excellently, however you can also use pythontutor.com to visualize execution.

[this will visually show you what happened with your old code and why it was broken](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+recursion(x%29%3A%0D%0A++++answer+%3D+0%0D%0A++++if(+x+%3E+10+%29%3A%0D%0A++++++++answer+%2B%3D1%0D%0A++++++++return+recursion(+x+-+1%29%0D%0A++++return+answer%0D%0Arecursion(15%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make answer a global variable:

```
answer = 0

def recursion(x):
    global answer
    ...
```

Comment: well thats an interesting solution I would not have thought of +1 since it will be easy for OP to understand ... even if in general you want to avoid globals

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that every time you call recursively the function the value of answer is set to 0. You can change it to:

```
answer = 0

def recursion(x):
    global answer
    if( x > 10 ):
        answer += 1
        return recursion( x - 1)
    return answer

recursion(15)
```

And a better implementation would be:

```
def recursion(x):
    if( x > 10 ):
        return 1 + recursion(x - 1)
    return 0
```

Comment: So by typing your global answer on line 4, you're calling answer into the method, which allows for the assignment answer += 1. Oh thanks nice, haven't used globals before

Comment: That's right, one thing is that you need to reset answer every time you want to call the function (using this implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Because the `answer` you define is in local scope .

It means the `answer` in this function call is not the same as in last call .

Your code should be

```
def recursion(x , answer):
    if( x > 10 ):
        answer +=1
        return recursion( x - 1 , answer)
    return answer
print(recursion(15 , 0))
```

Comment: solid functional programing example solution +1

Answer (score 0):

Cuz your answer is a local variable,every time you call the function,there is a "new answer para",just like that:

recursion(15):answer=0 answer+=1

recursion(14):answer=0 answer+=1

...

recursion(10):answer=0 jump if then return the answer to recursion(11),
then to recursion(12)......
the right way for your program should be:

```
answer = 0
def recursion(x):
    global answer
    if( x > 10 ):
        answer +=1
        return recursion( x - 1)
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `answer` allways return 0.

A better solution would:

```
def recursion(x, answer):
    if( x > 10 ):
        answer +=1
        return recursion( x - 1, answer)
    return answer
recursion(15, 0)
```